# cakephp set values to model before saving form data

Tags: forms, cakephp

i'm learning CakePHP. I want to submit form data to database and just before saving, I wish to modify few fields. Here is what I tried:

```
public function addProduct() {

    $this->layout = false;
    $this->render ( false );

    $this->loadModel ( 'Product' );

    $this->Product->create();

    $conditions = array('Product.category_id' => $this->request->data["categoryproduct"],
                        'Product.company_id' => $this->request->data["companyproduct"],
                        'Product.name' => $this->request->data["name"]
                    );

    $product = $this->Product->find ( 'first', array ('conditions' => $conditions ) );

    if ($product)
        echo "duplicate";
    else{

        $discount = $this->request->data["discount"];

        if($discount>0){
            $cost = $this->request->data["cost"];
            $this->Product->costforyou = intval($cost - $cost * $discount / 100);
        }
        else
            $this->Product->costforyou = 0;

        $this->Product->category_id = $this->request->data["categoryproduct"];
        $this->Product->company_id = $this->request->data["companyproduct"];
        $this->Product->create_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        $this->Product->status = "active";

        if ($this->Product->save($this->request->data)) {
            echo "Product added";
        } else {
            echo "Error in adding product";
        }
    }
}
```

But all the fields that I'm setting manually are not getting their data. I tried to have a look at CakePHP books but couldn't find anything there.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. Here is my new code:

```
public function addProduct() {

    $this->layout = false;
    $this->render ( false );

    $this->loadModel ( 'Product' );

    $this->Product->create();

    $conditions = array('Product.category_id' => $this->request->data["categoryproduct"],
                        'Product.company_id' => $this->request->data["companyproduct"],
                        'Product.name' => $this->request->data["name"]
                    );

    $product = $this->Product->find ( 'first', array ('conditions' => $conditions ) );

    if ($product)
        echo "duplicate";
    else{

        $discount = $this->request->data["discount"];
        $costforyou = 0;

        if($discount>0){
            $cost = $this->request->data["cost"];
            $costforyou = intval($cost - $cost * $discount / 100);
        }

        $this->request->data["category_id"] = $this->request->data["categoryproduct"];
        $this->request->data["company_id"] = $this->request->data["companyproduct"];
        $this->request->data["costforyou"] = $costforyou;
        $this->request->data["createdate"] = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        $this->request->data["status"] = "active";

        if ($this->Product->save($this->request->data)) {
            echo "Product added";
        } else {
            echo "Error in adding product";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use this [beforeSave()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave)

It's convenient method for modifying data before saving.